# Swift 4 Struct property started with a number

Tags: json, swift, variables

so I'm trying to request an api with json decoder using a decodable struct, the problem is that one of the json's property returned starts with a number like "24h_change" : "12323", the question is how to convert that property into a variable, here's my code:

```
struct CoinModel : Decodable {

let 24h_volume_usd : String? // here's the problem
let id : String?
let name : String?
let symbol :String?
let rank: String?
let price_usd: String?
}
```

the api returns

```
[{
"id": "bitcoin",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"symbol": "BTC",
"rank": "1",
"price_usd": "8660.0",
"24h_volume_usd": "1231213"
}]
```

ViewController

```
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiUrl) { (data, Reponse, err) in

        if err != nil{
            print("error getting JSON")
        }
        guard let data = data else{return}

        do{
            let JSON = try JSONDecoder().decode([CoinModel].self, from: data)

            self.coinArray = JSON


        }catch let err {

            print (err)
        }

     }.resume()
```

Comment: Property names *cannot* start with a digit. You need a custom key mapping `CodingKeys`, as demonstrated in the referenced Q&A.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981379/2303865

Comment: Thank you so much! works perfectly