# Parsing CoinMarketCap API using Swift's Decodable protocol

Tags: json, swift

I have read [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol?noredirect=1&lq=1) It does not address my specific use case where string literal number values are used as root dictionaries.

Also [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol) answer from Imanou Petit. [Can't decode JSON data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981198/cant-decode-json-data-from-api) answer from Leo Dabus.

The currencies are dictionaries themselves represented by literal string numbers inside of the `data` dictionary so this is throwing me off. I am looking for the most Swifty 4 model using enums where it is easy to see what containers correspond to what dictionaries.

p.s. David Berry gave a great answer below which I have implemented. If anyone else has other approaches to get to the same result I'd love to see different suggestions. Maybe there are some newer Swift 4 methods that are not well known yet or other design patterns.

**Code**

```
struct RawServerResponse {

    enum RootKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case btc = "1"
        case eth = "1027"
        case iota = "1720"
        case ripple = "52"
        case neo = "1376"
        case quotes
        case USD
    }

    enum BaseKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, symbol, maxSupply = "max_supply"
    }

    enum QuotesKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case USD
    }

    enum USDKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price, marketCap = "market_cap"
    }

    let data: String
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    let maxSupply: Double
    let price: Double
    let marketCap: Double
}

extension RawServerResponse: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // data
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootKeys.self)
        data = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .data)

        // id
        let idContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: BaseKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        id = try idContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id) 

        // price
        let priceContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: USDKeys.self, forKey: .USD)
        price = try priceContainer.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)

    }

}
```

**API / JSON**
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/

```
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17041575.0, 
        "total_supply": 17041575.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8214.7, 
                "volume_24h": 5473430000.0, 
                "market_cap": 139991426153.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0.09, 
                "percent_change_24h": 2.29, 
                "percent_change_7d": -2.44
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1526699671
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "website_slug": "ethereum", 
        "rank": 2, 
        "circulating_supply": 99524121.0, 
        "total_supply": 99524121.0, 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 689.891, 
                "volume_24h": 2166100000.0, 
                "market_cap": 68660795252.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0.13, 
                "percent_change_24h": 2.51, 
                "percent_change_7d": 2.54
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1526699662
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a simpler approach to the data, view the "data" as a collection of keyed, identical responses, likewise, the "quotes" is a keyed collection of Quotes.

```
struct RawServerResponse : Decodable {
    enum Keys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }

    let data : [String:Base]
}

struct Base : Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case symbol = "symbol"
        case maxSupply = "max_supply"
        case quotes = "quotes"
    }

    let id : Int64
    let name : String
    let symbol : String
    let maxSupply : Double?
    let quotes : [String:Quote]
}

struct Quote : Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case price = "price"
        case marketCap = "market_cap"
    }

    let price :  Double
    let marketCap : Double
}
```

Then, if you really need to access the individual keyed values out of those simpler structures, you can provide computed accessors:

```
extension RawServerResponse {
    enum BaseKeys : String {
        case btc = "1"
        case eth = "1027"
    }

    var eth : Base? { return data[BaseKeys.eth.rawValue] }
    var btc : Base? { return data[BaseKeys.btc.rawValue] }
}
```

And, likewise you could create similar accessors for currencies:

```
extension Base {
    enum Currencies : String {
        case usd = "USD"
    }

    var usd : Quote? { return quotes[Currencies.usd.rawValue]}
}
```

Once you have this part settled, then [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol) from your original question will show you how to flatten the structure if that's what you want.  Essentially it boils down to changing the computed properties into `let` properties that you would set as part of the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, those parts I just typed into the answer instead of copying from Xcode :)  and the var statements need return inserted at the obvious place.

Comment: I updated the extensions to be on the correct classes and syntax.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Took me a second to realize that "flattened out" meant creating value properties and initializer.

Comment: Forgot a question. If I have an object that contains all the data from the API i.e. `let allData = response.apiData` how do I loop through only the "symbol" key? Reason I ask is because with this API each "symbol" exists in a separate currency dictionary within a parent root data dictionary. Currently I can only retrieve separate currency symbols via `btcSymbol = rawResponse.btc?.symbol`. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use map: `for symbol in resp.data.values.map({ $0.symbol })`

Comment: Although it sounds like you probably want to use the first technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556178/3203487) to restructure the data and change the key of `apiData` to `symbol` instead of an arbitrary number.